# Multiple thread accessing and editing the same double array

Tags: c#, arrays, parallel-processing, arrayaccess

I need to iterate through every double in an array to do the "Laplacian Smoothing", "mixing values" with neighbour doubles.

I'll keep stored values in a temp clone array update the original at the end.

Pseudo code:

```cs
double[] A = new double[1000];
// Filling A with values...

double[] B = A.Clone as double[];

for(int loops=0;loops<10;loops++){ // start of the loop

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){ // iterating through all doubles in the array
    // Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) => {

       double v= A[i];
       B[i]-=v;
       B[i+1]+=v/2;
       B[i-1]+=v/2;
       // here i'm going out of array bounds, i know. Pseudo code, not relevant.

    }
    // });
}
A = B.Clone as double[];
```

With `for` it works correctly. "Smoothing" the values in the array.

With `Parallel.For()` I have some access sync problems: threads are colliding and some values are actually not stored correctly. Threads access and edit the array at the same index many times.

(I haven't tested this in a linear array, i'm actually working on a multidimensional array[x,y,z] ..)

How can I solve this?

I was thinking to make a separate array for each thread, and do the sum later... but I need to know the thread index and I haven't found anywhere in the web. (I'm still interested if a "thread index" exist even with a totally different solution...).

I'll accept any solution.

Comment: Why don't you check [range partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl)

Comment: You can also read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism

Comment: Instead of looping over all values in `A` and adjusting 3 values in `B` (this gives conflicts if 2 threads are working on overlapping `B` indices). Why not loop over every `B` value and calculate them from 3 `A` values (`B[i] += ((A[i-1] + A[i+1])/2)-A[i]`) since A doesn't change concurrent reads should pose no problem. Also keep in mind that the pseudo code (and this solution) crash on the edges of the array, I assume you fixed that in the real code

Comment: @knoop because my math will be more complex than that. Maybe i can do that, but the math will become 10x more complex. Nice idea.

Comment: Keep in mind that the question asked here is not about your full code but about the dumbed down pseudo code you provided. And that is generally one of the tradeoffs of parallel programming. The actual calculations get more complex but because you can do them in parallel you can get efficiency. You could try something with `Interlocked.CompareExchange(...)` and spin on failed changes (though it would then probably help to split the chunks in bigger blocks to limit collisions)

Comment: @knoop there can be no collisions and this can be solved in one go. I can just preallocate an array copy for each thread and then sum all the resulting arrays toghether. I just need the thread index inside Parallel.For , do you know who can i get that int value?
For parallelDegree=4 it would be an int ranging from 0 to 3, that i can use indise parallel.for.

Comment: It's really hard to discuss this because you have completely different code in mind. The calculation given in the question is so lightweight that combining arrays afterwards will be just as expensive. Also in the question case you could do with 3 temp arrays (one for the `i-1` part, one for the `i` part and one for the `i+1` part), no need for an array/thread. so first pass will fill those 3 arrays and then a second pass can loop over all values in `B` and combine them. But I'm expecting that once again will probably not work for the code you have in your head. So I'm out, good luck though:)

Comment: @knoop i'm working with a discrete 3d laplacian, each point is surrounded by 26 other points. My code is 300 lines long, and uses rhinoceros + grasshopper libraries. I don't know the correct terms to explain. If a "thread index" existed i would have already finished with that and posted here the solution. I wonder why it doesn't exist.
For now the best idea is your B>A instead A>B ... but i'll still need my original question for another part of the code. Thanks for your help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need one of the more advanced overloads of the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) method:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally);
```

> Executes a for loop with thread-local data in which iterations may run in parallel, loop options can be configured, and the state of the loop can be monitored and manipulated.

This looks quite intimidating with all the various lambdas it expects. The idea is to have each thread work with local data, and finally merge the data
at the end. Here is how you could use this method to solve your problem:

```
double[] A = new double[1000];
double[] B = (double[])A.Clone();
object locker = new object();
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};
Parallel.For(0, A.Length, parallelOptions,
    localInit: () => new double[A.Length], // create temp array per thread
    body: (i, state, temp) =>
    {
        double v = A[i];
        temp[i] -= v;
        temp[i + 1] += v / 2;
        temp[i - 1] += v / 2;
        return temp; // return a reference to the same temp array
    }, localFinally: (localB) =>
    {
        // Can be called in parallel with other threads, so we need to lock
        lock (locker)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < localB.Length; i++)
            {
                B[i] += localB[i];
            }
        }
    });
```

I should mention that the workload of the above example is too granular, so I wouldn't expect large improvements in performance from the parallelization. Hopefully your actual workload is more chunky. If for example you have two nested loops, parallelizing only the outer loop will work greatly because the inner loop will provide the much needed chunkiness.

---

**Alternative solution:** Instead of creating auxiliary arrays per thread, you could just update directly the B array, and use locks only when processing an index in the dangerous zone near the boundaries of the [partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create):

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, A.Length), parallelOptions, range =>
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
        {
            bool shouldLock = i < range.Item1 + 1 || i >= range.Item2 - 1;
            if (shouldLock) Monitor.Enter(locker, ref lockTaken);
            double v = A[i];
            B[i] -= v;
            B[i + 1] += v / 2;
            B[i - 1] += v / 2;
            if (shouldLock) { Monitor.Exit(locker); lockTaken = false; }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(locker);
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer by including an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears that modulus can solve pretty much all my problems.
Here a really simplified version of the working code:
(the big script is 3d and unfinished... )

```
private void RunScript(bool Go, ref object Results)
  {
    if(Go){
      LaplacianSmooth(100);
      // Needed to restart "RunScript" over and over
      this.Component.ExpireSolution(true);
    }
    else{
      A = new double[count];
      A[100] = 10000;
      A[500] = 10000;
    }
    Results = A;
  }

  // <Custom additional code> 
  public static int T = Environment.ProcessorCount;
  public static int count = 1000;
  public double[] A = new double[count];
  public double[,] B = new double[count, T];

  public void LaplacianSmooth(int loops){
    for(int loop = 0;loop < loops;loop++){

      B = new double[count, T];

      // Copying values to first column of temp multidimensional-array
      Parallel.For(0, count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = T }, i => {
        B[i, 0] = A[i];
        });

      // Applying Laplacian smoothing
      Parallel.For(0, count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = T }, i => {
        int t = i % 16;
        // Wrapped next and previous element indexes
        int n = (i + 1) % count;
        int p = (i + count - 1) % count;
        double v = A[i] * 0.5;
        B[i, t] -= v;
        B[p, t] += v / 2;
        B[n, t] += v / 2;
        });

      // Copying values back to main array
      Parallel.For(0, count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = T }, i => {
        double val = 0;
        for(int t = 0;t < T;t++){
          val += B[i, t];
        }
        A[i] = val;
        });
    }
  }
```

[image: Multithreaded linear laplacian smooth on grasshopper]

There are no "collisions" with the threads, as confirmed by the result of "Mass Addition" (a sum) that is constant at 20000.

Thanks everyone for the tips!